# Настройка Vite в Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, vite, laravel-9

В последних версиях Laravel в коробке идет Vite, который у меня никак не хочет работать нормально. В данный момент есть 2 основные проблемы:

1. При сборке vite build он бросает все файлы в папку public/build/assets, хотя, насколько я понимаю, все должно падать в public/assets.
2. Vite собирает только те файлы, которые попадаются в js и css моего проекта - это указано в конфиге. Но как добавить в конфиг и все blade-файлы, чтобы из них он тоже собирал картинки?

И вообще, может быть кто-то поделится правильным конфигом, который используется в повседневной работе?

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/scss/app.scss',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Обработка URL](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite#url-processing)

При использовании Vite и ссылках на ресурсы в HTML, CSS или JS вашего приложения необходимо учитывать несколько предостережений. Во-первых, если вы ссылаетесь на активы с абсолютным путем, Vite не будет включать актив в сборку; поэтому вы должны убедиться, что актив доступен в вашем общедоступном каталоге.

При ссылке на относительные пути ресурсов
вы должны помнить, что пути относятся к файлу, в котором они указаны. Любые активы, на которые ссылается относительный путь, будут переписаны, версионированы и объединены Vite.

```
public/
  taylor.png
resources/
  js/
    Pages/
      Welcome.vue
  images/
    abigail.png
```

В следующем примере показано, как Vite будет обрабатывать относительные и абсолютные URL-адреса:

```html
<!-- Этот актив не обрабатывается Vite и не будет включен в сборку. -->
<img src="/taylor.png">

<!-- Этот актив будет переписан, версионирован и объединен Vite. -->
<img src="../../images/abigail.png">
```

[Обработка статических ресурсов с помощью Vite](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite#blade-processing-static-assets)

При ссылке на активы в вашем JavaScript или CSS Vite автоматически обрабатывает и версионирует их. Кроме того, при создании приложений на основе Blade Vite также может обрабатывать статические ресурсы, на которые вы ссылаетесь, исключительно в шаблонах Blade.

Однако для того, чтобы осуществить это,
вам нужно сообщить Vite о ваших ресурсах, импортировав статические ресурсы в точку входа приложения. Например, если вы хотите обрабатывать и версионировать все изображения, хранящиеся в `resources/images`, и все шрифты, хранящиеся в `resources/fonts`, вы должны добавить следующее в точку входа вашего приложения `resources/js/app.js`:

```js
import.meta.glob([
  '../images/**',
  '../fonts/**',
]);
```

Эти активы теперь будут обрабатываться Vite при запуске `npm run build`. Затем вы можете ссылаться на эти активы в шаблонах Blade, используя метод `Vite::asset`, который вернет URL-адрес версии для данного актива:

```html
<img src="{{ Vite::asset('resources/images/logo.png') }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы правильно работали статистические изображения в CSS файлах как background-image: url(/img/main/image.png) при npm run dev и npm run build мне помогло:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    publicDir: 'public',
    base: '/',
    build: {
        assetsDir: '',
        copyPublicDir: false,
    },
});
```